# Math.factor(j) error when using data.table created from .xlsx import in R

Tags: r, data.table, xlsx

I am using information from a base data.table to pull data from other data.tables as in the following example:

```
test <- function() {
    library(data.table)

    test.dt <-     data.table(id=c("abc","xyz","ijk"),type=c("1","1","0"),line.position=1:3)
    counts.dt <- data.table(
            abc=c(10,NA,NA,NA),xyz=c(20,30,NA,NA),ijk=c(10,10,10,10),X2abc=NA,X3abc=1:4)

    print(test.dt)
    print(counts.dt)
    test.dt[,count:=sum(!is.na(counts.dt[[id]])),by=id]
    test.dt[,count.value:=counts.dt[line.position,id,with=FALSE],by=id]
    print(test.dt)
}
```

This works fine, and returns the expected result: a column that pulls uses (line.position,id) from a row in test.dt to grab values of counts(line.position,id).

However, I cannot repeat this with a more complex example that pulls data from a worksheet. I get the error: Error in Math.factor(j) : abs not meaningful for factors. This error is thrown right before the last print statement.

```
test2 <- function(
    file.directory="C:/Users/csnyder/Desktop/BootMethod/",
    file.name="test.xlsx",  
    resample.number=3
    )

{
    require("PBSmapping")
    require("xlsx")
    library(data.table)

    #Load input sheets
    file.path<-sprintf("%s%s",file.directory,file.name)
    excel.data<-read.xlsx(file.path,sheetIndex=1,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
    data.DT<-data.table(excel.data)
    excel.data<-read.xlsx(file.path,sheetIndex=2,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
    base.DT<-data.table(excel.data)
    excel.data<-read.xlsx(file.path,sheetIndex=3,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
    related.DT<-data.table(excel.data)
    excel.data<-NULL

    #add max rows to each ID type. with=TRUE, colnames used as variables.
    #get.text<-function(x){return(as.character(x))}
    base.DT<-base.DT[,Max.Sample:= sum(!is.na(data.DT[[ID]]),na.rm=TRUE),by=ID]

    base.length<-nrow(base.DT)
    base.DT[,Sub.Number:=1:base.length]
    base.DT[,Resample:=1]
    resample.base.DT<-base.DT

    #Add line numbers to data tables.
    data.DT[,Line:=1:nrow(data.DT)]
    related.DT[,Line:=1:nrow(related.DT)]

    #resample number added to base DT, then will make a for loop by resample numbers             and loop it.
    for(counter in 1:resample.number){
        base.DT<-rbindlist(list(base.DT,resample.base.DT[,Resample:=counter]))
    }
    #remove loop initiator
    base.DT<-base.DT[-(1:base.length)]
    #number rows
    base.DT[,Row.Number:=Resample*base.length+Sub.Number-base.length]

    #pick line to sample
    pick.row<-function(x){return(runif(1,1,x))}
    base.DT[,"Line":=runif(1,1,Max.Sample),with=FALSE]
    base.DT[,"Line":=round(runif(1,1,Max.Sample),digits=0),by=Row.Number]

    #Pull cell from data.DT (and related.DT) that has position corresponding to the         matching Row.Number and ID in base.DT
    base.DT[,From.Data:=data.DT[Line,ID,with=FALSE],by=ID]
    print(base.DT)
}
```

Now, the sheets from my excel workbook import what looks like (to me at least) the following:

Sheet1:

```
data.DT<-data.table(item1=c("AAAA","2XXX",780,684,614,39),item2=c("AAAA","XXX",10,314,NA,NA))
```

Sheet2:

```
base.DT<-data.table(ID=c("item1","item2"),Level=c("X2XXX","XXX"),Type=c("AAAA","AAAA"),P=c(1000,1000    ),Cat=c("AAAA","AAAA"),Day=c(NA,1))
```

Sheet3:

```
related.DT<-data.table(item1=c("AAAA","2XXX",1,1,1,NA),item2=c("AAAA","XXX",1,1,NA,NA))
```

At my current location, I can't upload a workbook. Replacing the excel imports with the direct calls above seems to fix the problem. At risk of not having a reproducible question, I have to ask: Has anyone run into this problem or have an idea of how to resolve it? Or perhaps I'm going about this in a convoluted way--work-arounds are equally welcomed! If an excel workbook is needed to fully understand my question, let me know and I'll try my best to upload one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's when one gets that error:

```
abs(as.factor(5))
# Error in Math.factor(as.factor(5)) : abs not meaningful for factors
```

You have factors because of `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in your `read`'s and because one or more of the elements in one of the columns that you thought was all numbers, is actually not a number, but a string. Check which of your columns are factors, by running

```
sapply(dt, class)
```

and take it from there.

---

Edit from Arun: You should note that when converting, say, `5` from `factor` to a number, you should first convert it to a character using `as.character` and then to numeric or integer using `as.numeric` or `as.integer`:

```
x <- factor(5)

# correct conversion
as.numeric(as.character(x))
# [1] 5

# incorrect conversion if you want the number coerced to numeric type
as.numeric(x) # gets the levels of factor numeric instead
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Lesson Learned: Importing from excel might result in unexpected Types. Using the suggestions from eddi and Arun, I was able to figure out the Types of all of my columns and make sure that they matched the header type of data.table (i.e. character). The Math.Factor error was driving me crazy, because I was looking for a factor issue; it was really a type mismatch issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For those who might encounter the same problem, this didn't work until I implemented eddi's and arun's solutions. The conversion to character and then numeric was key.